# How make QuerySet of items which contain other model

Tags: django, django-models

So i have one model with list of all item i have.
And other model which has Foreign-Key to to my main model... How to Make query set object. Of all items from first model which contain my second model?

```
class Music(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField()
    duration=models.IntegerField()


class Playlist(models.Model):
    misic=models.ForeignKey(Music)
```

How to Make query set obj of Music which is in Playlist? Then iwant to make `.aggregate` to count duration of all playlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to Make query set obj of Music which is in Playlist?

Something like this.

```
playlist = Playlist.objects.get(**conditions)
music = Music.objects.filter(playlist = playlist)
```

> Then iwant to make .aggregate to count duration of all playlist.

Use a Django annotation with the `Sum` class (django.db.models).

```
from django.db.models import Sum
qs = Music.objects.filter(playlist = playlist).annotate(total = 
     Sum('duration'))
```

**Update**

(After reading @Pol's comment)

> Music model has not attribute playlist ...

1. Are you getting an error? If so post the code you used and stack trace. I tested out your models locally and the above given filter/annotation worked fine.
2. Your models don't make sense to me. I'd expect `Music` and `Playlist` models to have a many to many relationship. Failing which a `Playlist` should have many `Music` instances associated. I.e. Foreign Key should be inside `Music`, not other way round as you have now.

**Update 2**

(After reading @Pol's comment)

> Yep... You right... It has to be many to many.. but it's not... What should i do? And Music is already made big table in database. I just need to add support of playlists....

There is no need to change your `Music` model or underlying table. You can add a new model `Playlist` with the following structure:

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    music = models.ManyToManyField(Music)
```

You can now **drop** the existing playlist table and execute `python manage.py syncdb`. The new table for `Playlist` and join tables for many to many will be created.

That said I must add a **statutory warning** that this is not a good way of managing changes to your models. You will be much better off using a migration tool such as [South](http://south.aeracode.org/). South will let you handle migrations much more gracefully, especially when there is data change involved.

Comment: Yep... You right... It has to be many to many.. but it's not... What should i do? And Music is already made big table in database. I just need to add support of playlists....

Comment: OK... Thanks... I knew about migration... I just though that there is more simple way.... without changing the model of Playlist... Ok i will do counting in circle... Because much work were done.